# Coherence of subrings of K[[X,Y]]

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables, galois-representations, coherence

Let $K[[X,Y]]$ be a two-variables formal power series ring over a field $K$. Consider a sub-ring $\iota \colon A \subset K[[X,Y]]$.

### Q. Is A coherent? $\quad$ Or is it automatic that $\iota$ is faithfully flat ?

For example, we can embed the infinitely many variables power series ring as

$K[[T_1,T_2,T_3,...]] \subset K[[X,Y]]$.

If the answer of the question is yes, we can prove the coherence of $K[[T_1,T_2,...]]$.

Comment: "If the answer of the question is yes": There are two questions.  The answer to the second question is no: take for $A$ the complete $K$-subalgebra generated by $X^2,XY,Y^2$.

Comment: The complete $K$-subalgebra $A$ generated by $X^2, XY, Y^2$ is coherent. Is it easy that $\iota A \hookrightarrow K[[X,Y]]$ is $NOT$ flat?

Comment: Yes. Note that $A$ is local with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}=(X^2,XY,Y^2)$. Now $K[[X,Y]]$ is a finite $A$-module but it is not free since $[K(\!(X,Y)\!):\mathrm{Frac}(A)]=2$ while $\dim_K(K[[X,Y]]/\mathfrak{m}K[[X,Y]])=3$. (Alternatively, $K[[X,Y]]$ is regular but $A$ isn't).